# Recover user files after Windows 10 Fall update

Tags: windows-10

The recent Windows 10 update has "lost" many of my settings and customisations for non-Microsoft programmes. (I am especially damaged by the complete loss of the history and settings for Textpad.)

Am I right to assume that such files should be saved in

C:\Windows.old\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming ?

More importantly - if my settings files have not been saved there then are they gone and a rollback would be pointless?

Comment: Yes, they should be there,

Comment: Of course if Textpad doesn’t save your recent file history there then they won’t be stored there

Comment: Textpad saves all sorts of vital information in  C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Helios\TextPad\7\ConfigState.xml -- which Microsoft wiped as part of their update.

Comment: The ConfigState.xml file is not in Windows.old
The question is -- does a rollback "just" reinstate Windows...Roaming from Windows.old...Roaming and so if the file was not saved then am I just doomed?